# Video textures inside the cube

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-video, webgl

How could I import videos to my webGL website and use them as textures?

I am trying to achieve the effect where user has been put inside the cube and there are four sides of the cube where he could watch the videos.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that might help you to get started:

- [WebGL getting started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL)
- [WebGL video texutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebGL/Animating_textures_in_WebGL)

Second one explains to how to embed videos as textures for your 3dobjects.

So, you could create four planes in total, and display one video/texture for each plane.